# How do I share folders in Xubuntu?

Tags: networking, xubuntu, samba, shared-folders

How do I share folders in Xubuntu like in Ubuntu? I found no settings or options to share folders on my network, I do have Samba installed. I don't know what else to try. Is there a command that I can try in terminal for Xubuntu? I do see my Xubuntu machine from other computers on my network, but shows empty when I access it on other computers. Ubuntu is more user friendly for such purpose.

Comment: Try package `system-config-samba`. It is a simple graphical tool for most common samba options, including sharing.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it, but I every time I try to install via terminal or software center, I keep on getting installation errors. other solutions?

Comment: I struggle a lot with xubuntu to get the folders on it shared, samba is installed but not helpful. Xubuntu is great on my old pc, with not userfriendly with sharing folders. Please help

Comment: Then you have to ask another question and to describe what problems do you have during install. And if you seek for other solution, it may be not so simple. Look at `/etc/samba/smb.conf` and try to understand it's structure. It has shared folders' definitions.

Comment: @Orosjopie What installation errors are you getting? Can you edit your question to include the complete and exact text of the error messages?

Answer (score 13):

Menu --> Settings --> Shared Folders

Or...

Execute:

```
shares-admin
```

Font: http://linuxuserlog.blogspot.com.br/2014/01/como-compartilhar-pastas-arquivos-no.html

Comment: This doesn't work for me in Xubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 7):

Install Samba (package name `system-config-samba`). If you are using Xubuntu 13.10 then also install gksu. Then go to `Settings Manager -> Samba` and add the desired shares.

Alternatively you can edit the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file and add something like this

```
[set share name here]
    path = set path here
    comment = set description here
    writeable = no
    browseable = yes
    read only = yes
    guest ok = yes
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately neither `shares-admin` (crashes) nor `system-config-samba` (deprecated) work in recent Xubuntu releases. Other than in Nautilus we do not have an option to share directories from Thunar.

This apparently means that as of today we do not have a working graphical method to setup Samba shares in Xubuntu.

So after installing samba and defining a Samba user with:

```
sudo apt install samba
sudo smbpasswd -a [user]  ## [user] must already exist for Xubuntu
```

We can use the command `net usershare` [for adding directories](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143024/how-can-i-create-a-samba-share-from-the-command-line). Because of  better copy & paste ability I find it more convenient to create an entry in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

```
[share name]
    path = full path to shared directory
    comment = optional description
    writeable = yes
    browseable = yes
    read only = yes
    guest ok = yes
```

Further options for `smb.conf` can be read in the [Samba documentation](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html). The named share will be available after a [restart of the samba server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79078/how-to-restart-samba-server).