# Xubuntu bugs, Samba, sharing services not installed

Tags: networking, xubuntu, samba, nfs, thunar

Trying to share between 2 xubuntu machines on the same network:

`sudo apt install samba` from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/236751/68396), `sudo apt install system-config-samba` from [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1670223&p=11384263#post11384263).

`shares-admin` from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/408404/68396) didn't work initially - "Sharing services are not installed". Tried

`sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-server` from [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1404616&p=8814479#post8814479), now means I can open `shares-admin`, unlock it, try to add folders, and it crashes with

> Segmentation fault

Opening Samba from the menu gives:

> Failed to execute gksu system-config-samba. Failed to execute child
>   process "gksu"

```
sudo apt install gksu
```

> Package gksu is not available

Can't edit the shortcut in the menu because although the icon appears and is clickable, the entry isn't present in menu editor.

```
sudo system-config-samba
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/sbin/system-config-samba", line 45, in module
>
> ```
> mainWindow.MainWindow(debug_flag)
> ```
>
> File "/usr/share/system-config-samba/mainWindow.py", line 121, in **init**
>
> ```
> self.basic_preferences_win = basicPreferencesWin.BasicPreferencesWin(self, self.xml, self.samba_data, self.samba_backend, self.main_window)
> ```
>
> File "/usr/share/system-config-samba/basicPreferencesWin.py", line 97, in
>   **init**
>
> ```
> self.admin = libuser.admin()
> ```
>
> SystemError: could not open configuration file `/etc/libuser.conf': No such file or directory

```
sudo apt install thunar-shares-plugin
```

> Unable to locate package

```
sudo /etc/init.d/samba restart
```

> sudo: /etc/init.d/samba: command not found

[This folder](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1766246) isn't present.

Does anyone have any tips for how to setup sharing on Xubuntu 18.10 & 18.04? This seems like it should be really simple and has immediately become nightmarish. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much all of your links are outdated.

[1] If you really want to use system-config-samba:

```
sudo touch /etc/libuser.conf
```

Then:

```
sudo -H system-config-samba
```

[2] If you need to restart any samba services it's:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

[3] Do not use **shares-admin**

[4] All the ... um ... stuff you read about changing workgroup names, local master, preferred master, etc.. is irrelevant when using samba in an all Linux network since it's not using NetBIOS. It uses mDNS ( Avahi ) and samba will automatically register itself to the rest of the network using it.

Comment: useful intel, thanks. Before I try the above, your tone (already hard to be sure in text) suggests system-samba-config - and possible others - are outdated. Is there a better way of doing things than the method you've advised above? NFS? https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-file-system.html.en

Comment: ran into another minefield of issues, requires users & password setups that still don't work, able to access but not write despite setting the permissions accordingly. Now trying https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/11/easy-nfs-share-setup-in-ubuntu-linux.html Amazed how problematic this is.

Comment: I haven't used NFS since the Berlin Wall came down so I can't help you with that. Share access and R/W ability does not necessarily require credentials - it all depends on how you set up the share. If you edit your original post by adding the output of the following command I may be able to assist you with that: "testparm -s" As far and users and passwords remember that unlike Windows in Samba there are two passwords for every user: The local login password and the samba password. You set the samba password with this command: "sudo smbpasswd -a user-name"